# sapui5 | Odata | Navigationproperties are not supported in ABAP select options

Tags: odata, sapui5

When trying to filter a query by restraining a sub-collection's value, I get the following error: **Navigationproperties are not supported in ABAP select options**

What does this mean?

The url is:

```
https://<myCRM>/sap/c4c/odata/v1/c4codata/ProductCollection?$expand=ProductCategoryAssignment&$filter=ProductCategoryAssignment/ProductCategoryDescription/content eq 'TEST CONTENT'
```

Note: it's a V1 OData.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are requesting data from an OData V2 service.
Here filtering on expanded items is not supported.
Thist is only supported as of OData V4.
(See my blog 
https://blogs.sap.com/2017/12/12/odata-v4-code-based-implementation-overview/)
Best Regards,
Andre